# MySQL One to Many order by number found in joined table

Tags: php, mysql

Two tables:

```
table_a
-------
table_a_id: (primary, int)

table_b
-------
table_a_id: (index, int, from table_a)
table_b_value: (varchar)
```

A one to many relationship between table_a_id and table_b_value.

Given a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(table_a_id) FROM table_a 
JOIN table_b ON table_a.table_a_id=table_b.table_a_id
```

I want to order by the number of occurrences of table_a_id in table_b. I'm not really sure how to write this in MySQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(table_b.table_a_id) AS count 
FROM table_a 
JOIN table_b ON table_b.table_a_id = table_a.id 
GROUP BY table_b.table_a_id 
ORDER_BY count DESC
```

Comment: Well that would give me the total count, but I don't think it wouldn't order the query by the total count, which is what I want to do.

Comment: I updated the post, look now ( didn't notice last few lines of your question )

Comment: IDs in table A that don't appear in table B won't be counted in the result. Use a left join, group by `table_a.id` and count `table_a.id` to resolve this.

Comment: @outis I think @Finbarr asked for "number of occurrences of table_a_id in table_b" :)

Comment: @Kerno: if a table_a_id doesn't appear in table_b, it occurs 0 times; that a given table_a_id doesn't appear in table_b doesn't mean it shouldn't appear in the result of the count query. I confess the formulation of the question is ambiguous enough that either interpretation could be the correct one. If we take "table_a_id" to mean "table_a.table_a_id", then the result should include those IDs occuring 0 times; if "table_a_id" refers to "table_b.table_a_id", then the result shouldn't include them (in which case the join is unnecessary).

Answer (score 1):

SELECT 
            a.table_a_id,
            COUNT(b.table_a_id) AS `a_count`
    FROM    table_a AS a
    LEFT JOIN   table_b AS b
        ON  a.table_a_id = b.table_a_id
    GROUP BY a.table_a_id
    ORDER BY `a_count`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to join the tables at all in this case?

```
SELECT table_a_id FROM table_b GROUP BY table_a_id order by count(table_a_id) desc
```

Comment: Because `count(table_a.table_a_id)` will always be 1, and Finbarr wants the count for `table_b.table_a_id`.

Comment: Whoops - typo from me - post edited (should have been FROM table_b)

Comment: That's better. However, IDs from table A that don't appear in table B won't appear in the result. The currently accepted answer has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using your example

```
SELECT table_a_id, COUNT(*)
FROM table_b
GROUP BY table_a_id
```

#### A real world example

If you want a table like:

```
post_id  comments_count
1        20
2        125
3        43
```

If you might need other information from the `A` table, you can:

```
select p.id, count(c.*) comments_count
from posts p
join comments c on c.post_id = p.id
group by p.id
```

If you don't need anything from the `A` table, you can simplify:

```
select post_id, count(*)
from comments
group by post_id
```